# How to properly construct and use API to feed different sections on a web page for data they require?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, rest, frontend

I am working on an article listing website. The site home page has 3 sections. On top it displays a slider/carousel with 3 slides followed by an article list with 6 items and a "Load more" button (to load next set of articles). After the list, there are 2 sections displaying spotlight or featured articles. The front-end uses react and each of this section is a component.

For back-end it uses REST API (Node + Mongodb). I can fetch all articles calling an API endpoint but i want to know how those 3 sections on the home page should consume it? Should i create and use separate API calls for each of the section? What would be the best way? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general i feel splitting each component responsibilities and have them handle their own calls is the best way to go, the code is clearer, easier to maintain and more scaleable.

However one thing to keep in mind is the expected network latency for your users.
In a high-latency situation with otherwise good bandwidth, many small requests will perform significantly worse than one large one.

You should also question when (if) you send one large response is all/most data available from it used? Or is most of it wasted on a state most users wont even reach?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am sort of new to mongodb. Please validate my understanding below if api calls are to be separated.
api.domain.com/articles/slides -> brings 3 articles for the slider
api.domain.com/articles -> brings 6 articles for the article list (will use pagination)
api.domain.com/articles/featured -> brings 2 articles for the featured section

This also needs separate collections (sliderArticles, featuredArticles) to be created. 
Can we create these collections on fly when author submits an article by marking it as featured and/or for slider and how?

Comment: yes your understanding is correct, the extra collections 'issue' depend on scale more than anything imo, however a boolean field thats index'd stating if an article is featured/slider should be more than fine. if you do end up choosing to create a new collection for those yes you can do it on the fly, just insert the document to the collection and it will be formed. – tom slabbaert 5 mins ago   Delete